# Auto translate mails in Apple's mail app

Tags: mail.app

I wonder if there is a way to auto-translate the mails in Apple mail app since it's very inconvenient to keep copying emails and pasting in a web translation site and so on. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Service that acts on a text and then you'll be able to select any text and see its translation. In order to do that, please install `trans` from here: [Translate-Shell Github](https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell). Place the binary somewhere in the system, for example `/usr/local/bin` directory. Then You'll have to create an Automator Workflow as a "Quick Action" (before it was called a Service).

[image: Automator new Service]

It'll look like that:

[image: Automator workflow for teanslation]

Then save it as `translate`. After that you'll be able to select any text, right click on it and select `Services -> translate`.

Here's how it works (translating your post into Polish language):

[image: Example translation]

Comment: I've downloaded the folder and placed it in the /usr/local but there is no file called trans in it. Any idea?

Comment: You've downloaded the project with source files. You'll have to compile it, or simply get the compiled version. There are instructions how to do it on the github page (or in README.md file).

Comment: For some reason I cannot see the top part in Automator which says "workflow receives current" ... as shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/OK8Pf.jpg Any idea why?

Comment: Good job so far :) You have to create a "Quick Action" in Automator, not an app/workflow etc. I'll update my answer. Sorry for the trouble it was called `Service` before.

Comment: I can also see that you have no permissions to run the `trans` you'll probably have to make it executable with that command in Terminal: `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/trans`.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Now when I run it I get this https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKm9L.png

Comment: What happens if you run `/usr/local/bin/trans :en -b "gratulacje"` in Terminal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106700/discussion-between-tak-and-mateusz-szlosek).